# How to stop header outside of tableView from disappearing when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, layout, keyboard

so for the life of me I can't figure out how to stop the header from scrolling outside the screen when the keyboard pops-up.

[Without keyboard engaged - header is where it should be | With keyboard engaged - header disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51qxx.png)

[My hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Qo5.png)

This seems like it should be a simple problem to fix, but I have played around with so many different layout settings and constraints and I just can't figure it out.  Does anyone have some suggestions for how I could make this work?

Comment: So it looks like the entire view moves up with the keypad.  Obviously when the keypad is visible there is less space so what do you want to happen?  Should the tableview reduce in vertical size?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Yes I would like the header to still be visible and the top cells to slide up when the keyboard comes up so that only the most bottom cells will be visible

Comment: Basically you need to give the header view a fixed height constraint then pin it to the top, give the button a fixed height constraint and then pin it to the bottom.  Then pin the top of the table to the bottom of the header and the bottom of the table to the top of the button.  Then when the keyboard appears you need to shrink the superview by the keyboard height and the only thing that can change height is the table.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using as there is a good WWDC video about adjusting for the keyboard in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TableHeader make it as section header by returning that view for Section 0 in viewForHeaderInSection method... that solves your problem.

Comment: It might be one possible method of solving the issue but if you look at the hierarchy it's not a TableHeader but a separate view above the table.

Comment: Yes, it is not a tableheader. Would it be easiest if I just convert it to a format using tableheaders?